# Kafka OAuth: Unrecognized SASL Login callback

Tags: oauth-2.0, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, sasl

What I am trying to do is:

```
Setup SASL/PLAIN for inter-broker communication

Setup SASL/PLAIN for Broker-Zookeeper communication

And Setup SASL/OAUTHBEARER for client-broker communication.
```

My server_jaas.conf is:

```
KafkaServer { 
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule required
    LoginStringClaim_sub="admin";

    org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
    username="admin"
    password="admin-secret"
    user_admin="admin-secret";
};

Client {
    org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
    username="zookeeper"
    password="zookeeper_secret";
};
```

Also I did set the following config options:

```
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN,OAUTHBEARER
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
sasl.server.callback.handler.class=br.com.jairsjunior.security.oauthbearer.OauthAuthenticateValidatorCallbackHandler
```

And I have used the jar provided here - https://github.com/jairsjunior/kafka-playground/tree/master/kafka-broker/kafka-with-oauth/libs

But the moment I start the Kafka server, I get the error:

```
Unrecognized SASL Login callback
(org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule)
javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException: Unrecognized SASL Login callback

at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.AbstractLogin$DefaultLoginCallbackHandler.handle(AbstractLogin.java:105)
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule.login(OAuthBearerLoginModule.java:261)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:755)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.AbstractLogin.login(AbstractLogin.java:60)
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.LoginManager.<init>(LoginManager.java:64)
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.LoginManager.acquireLoginManager(LoginManager.java:114)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:142)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:140)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.serverChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:82)
at kafka.network.Processor.<init>(SocketServer.scala:548)
at kafka.network.SocketServer.newProcessor(SocketServer.scala:247)
at kafka.network.SocketServer.$anonfun$addProcessors$1(SocketServer.scala:163)
at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:156)
at kafka.network.SocketServer.addProcessors(SocketServer.scala:162)
at kafka.network.SocketServer.$anonfun$createAcceptorAndProcessors$1(SocketServer.scala:150)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:52)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at kafka.network.SocketServer.createAcceptorAndProcessors(SocketServer.scala:145)
at kafka.network.SocketServer.startup(SocketServer.scala:94)
at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:250)
at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:38)
at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:75)
at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)



[2019-05-24 12:30:30,414] ERROR [KafkaServer id=240] Fatal error during   
KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException:    
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: An internal error occurred
at
org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.
configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:153)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create
(ChannelBuilders.java:140)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.serverChannelBuilder
(ChannelBuilders.java:82)
at kafka.network.Processor.<init>(SocketServer.scala:548)
at kafka.network.SocketServer.newProcessor(SocketServer.scala:247)
at kafka.network.SocketServer.$anonfun$addProcessors$1
(SocketServer.scala:163)
at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:156)
at kafka.network.SocketServer.addProcessors(SocketServer.scala:162)
at kafka.network.SocketServer.$anonfun$createAcceptorAndProcessors$1
(SocketServer.scala:150)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach
(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$
(ResizableArray.scala:52)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at kafka.network.SocketServer.createAcceptorAndProcessors
(SocketServer.scala:145)
at kafka.network.SocketServer.startup(SocketServer.scala:94)
at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:250)
at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup
(KafkaServerStartable.scala:38)
at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:75)
at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)



Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: An internal error occurred
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule.
login(OAuthBearerLoginModule.java:264)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:755)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000
(LoginContext.java:195)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv
(LoginContext.java:680)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.AbstractLogin.
login(AbstractLogin.java:60)
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.LoginManager.
<init>(LoginManager.java:64)
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.LoginManager.
acquireLoginManager(LoginManager.java:114)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure
(SaslChannelBuilder.java:142)
... 17 more
```

What I am missing here ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

sasl.login.callback.handler.class is used to specify which loginmodule the client requests tokens based on, and needs to be configured in both the broker and client. （I don't know why the broker also needs to be configured, but when I test it, the broker must also be configured, otherwise an error will be reported.）

sasl.server.callback.handler.class is a class used to specify the server-side validation of tokens sent by the client, which needs to be configured on the broker side.

Two handler class need to be configured. For example:

```
listener.name.sasl.oauthbearer.sasl.login.callback.handler.class=org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.secured.OAuthBearerLoginCallbackHandler
listener.name.sasl.oauthbearer.sasl.server.callback.handler.class=org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.secured.OAuthBearerValidatorCallbackHandler
```

The whole config for example:(use two mechanisms: OAuth and Plain, OAuth use AAD token)

Broker config:

```
listeners=SASL://x.x.x.x:9770
advertised.listeners=SASL://x.x.x.x:9770
listener.security.protocol.map=SASL:SASL_PLAINTEXT

sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=OAUTHBEARER,PLAIN

listener.name.sasl.plain.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="AdminName" password="AdminPassword" user_UserName="UserPassword";
listener.name.sasl.plain.sasl.server.callback.handler.class=com.XXXAuthenticateCallbackHandler

listener.name.sasl.oauthbearer.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule required clientId='BrokerApplicationId' clientSecret='BrokerApplicationSecret' scope='BrokerApplicationId/.default';
listener.name.sasl.oauthbearer.sasl.login.callback.handler.class=org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.secured.OAuthBearerLoginCallbackHandler
listener.name.sasl.oauthbearer.sasl.server.callback.handler.class=org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.secured.OAuthBearerValidatorCallbackHandler

sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url=https://login.microsoftonline.com/BrokerTenantId/discovery/v2.0/keys
sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url=https://login.microsoftonline.com/BrokerTenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token

authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer
allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=true
super.users=User:AdminName
```

Client config:

Plain:

```
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="UserName" password="UserPassword";
```

Oauth:

```
bootstrap.servers=xxxx:xxxx
compression.type=none
sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url=https://login.microsoftonline.com/ClientTenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
sasl.login.callback.handler.class=org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.secured.OAuthBearerLoginCallbackHandler
sasl.mechanism=OAUTHBEARER
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.jaas.config= \
  org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule required \
    clientId='ClientApplicationId' \
    scope='BrokerApplicationId/.default' \
    clientSecret='ClientApplicationSecret';
```